# Unable to install package in R

Tags: r, installation, package, tm, tidytext

I am getting the error below while installing a package:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to move temporary installation ‘E:\R-3.3.2\library\filed603811626\tidytext’ to ‘E:\R-3.3.2\library\tidytext
```

Please suggest how to resolve this error.

Comment: It is a warning. What do you get if you load the library? `library(name_of_package)`

Comment: Use remove.packages() and then *restart* Rstudio.

Comment: while installing the package I'm getting the below error.. 
In case of library("tm")
Error: package ‘NLP’ required by ‘tm’ could not be found

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install R in your main disk drive (most probably `C:/`)

This resolves quite a few problems with moving packages that R does when installing.

You can then install all required dependencies with `install.packages(c("tm", "tidytext"))`